# Remote desktop/vnc into a windows computer from a Ubuntu computer

Tags: windows, ubuntu, remote-desktop, vnc

I'm looking for a good solution that allows me to remote desktop a windows computer from a ubuntu computer.

If the software is open-source and in the standard repositories (so I just can apt-get install) that would be really great.

And what shall I install on the windows computer? 
I would really like it to use the standard windows users (and theirs passwords).

And it would also be great if more that one user could be logged in at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Gnome-RDP it should do what you're after (assuming you're using gnome anyway)

Comment: And what shall I install in the windows computer?

Comment: You don't need to install anything just enable remote control. Right click on my computer and do properties, switch to the remote tab and tick the remote desktop box.

Answer (score 1):

I use [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/) on my Windows system, and access it from Ubuntu with the default VNC viewer ([Vinagre](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Vinagre)). UltraVNC is about as fast as anything else, and its even better with Windows clients also using it, with the mirror driver.

(And fwiw, I use Chicken of the VNC on my Mac to the UltraVNC server. It's fast, even over WiFi.)

Answer (score 0):

Give [NoMachine](http://www.nomachine.com/download.php) a whirl.

> Moreover, **NX also can connect to
>   remote RDP and VNC servers**, relying on
>   the rdesktop and TightVNC clients by
>   encapsulating the RDP or RFB session
>   within the X11 session.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of stock Ubuntu (Not Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Mate,etc.) have a built in app called Remmina. This app can act as a RDP, VNC and SSH client. There is a dropdown next to where you enter the ip. (I haven't used ubuntu in a while, so my knowledge is kind of spotty) You can select the connection type from there.

There is also a app called KDE connect on kubuntu, but I don't know about it because I don't use KDE.